# Windows authentication on swagger api endpoint in IIS

Tags: api, iis, .net-core, swagger

I currently have a .net core api setup to use swagger. I need to protect the swagger documents with windows authentication. Since there isn't an actual swagger folder with swagger html files, it seems like i can't setup the authentication through IIS manager. Is there any way to do this?